# error : no resource identifier found for attribute 'text direction' in package 'android'

Tags: java, android, text, textview

Well i wanted my arabic app to switch text direction to (right to left) 
So i added this code:
android:textDirection="anyRtl"
and it shows like this :

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textDirection="anyRtl"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />
```

To All the textview in this java file . but this error comes out :
no resource identifier found for attribute 'text direction' in package 'android'
What should i do please help .. thanks a lot

Comment: Make sure  minSDKVersion is 17, or greater.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/switch"
        android:text="sometext"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i don't think it worked .. i have a lot of text views 4 may be .. and i'm just a beginner in java .. So little more help plz sir

Comment: Note: To enable right-to-left layout features for your app, you must set supportsRtl to "true" and set targetSdkVersion to 17 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

test by changing  textDirection="anyRtl"  by layout_gravity

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Comment: i did and still the same problem ..  the thing is that my app is a quiz game .. and when u start choosing the letters they start to  aligne from left to right .. u get the picture i hope .. 
i need them to aligne from right to left ...